# Symfony encore HTTPS dev server "not enough data"

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore

I am using Symfony and Encore for my web project. Node version is 20.5.0. I recently got a new macbook m2 and installed node and everything. But when running Encore server (webpack dev server) I get this issue:

```
➜  project git:(dev) ✗ NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider npm run dev

> encore dev-server  --open https://127.0.0.1:8000

Running webpack-dev-server ...

<i> [webpack-dev-server] SSL certificate: /Users/.../web/.../node_modules/.cache/webpack-dev-server/server.pem
[webpack-cli] Error: not enough data
    at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls/secure-context:280:15)
    at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:116:3)
    at Server.setSecureContext (node:_tls_wrap:1439:27)
    at Server (node:_tls_wrap:1303:8)
    at new Server (node:https:75:3)
    at Object.createServer (node:https:131:10)
    at Server.createServer (/Users/.../web/.../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:2528:57)
    at Server.initialize (/Users/.../web/.../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:1893:10)
    at Server.start (/Users/.../web/.../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:3358:16)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/.../web/.../node_modules/@webpack-cli/serve/lib/index.js:242:25)
```

webpack.config.js

```
.configureDevServerOptions(options => {
     options.server = {
     type: 'https',
     options: {
       pfx: path.join(process.env.HOME, '.symfony5/certs/default.p12'),
       }
     }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a step in setting up symfony server to use TLS. Fixed by running:

```
symfony server:ca:install
```

Stated in [this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html)